# Why is the ASCII-armored version of my OpenPGP public key so long?

Tags: pgp, openpgp

My OpenPGP key pair was generated by 2048 RSA. The ASCII-armored version of the public key is much longer than most others that I see on the OpenPGP key servers.

Mine is several screens worth of ASCII at 72 characters a line, totaling somewhere north of 44,000 characters. Most other public keys I see are about one screen's worth of ASCII.

Should I be worried about it or even revoke it? Key ID is [`86A8E28C`](http://pool.sks-keyservers.net/pks/lookup?op=vindex&search=0x86A8E28C), if any one wants a look at it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your key, two images are included, a revoked one and a valid one. Each of those occupies about 16KB in binary format, which will blow up by about 1/3 if ascii-armored (which pretty much equals base 64 encoding). `32000B*4/3` is a little bit more than 42000 characters (or bytes), which comes very close to the counted number of characters for the whole key (which also contains the keys, signatures, ...):

```
$ gpg --armor --export 86A8E28C | wc -c
45602
```

So, everything's fine, and the other keys you observed probably do not store a picture.